# Traefik get dashboard through domain "http://traefik.example.com/"

Tags: traefik

I have next configuration, docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /root/traefik/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
  whoami:
    # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
    image: traefik/whoami
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.docker.server`)"
```

And traefik.yml:

```
api: {}
```

Dynamic Configuration:

```
http:
  routers:
    api:
      rule: Host(`traefik.example.com`)
      service: api@internal
      middlewares:
        - auth
  middlewares:
    auth:
      basicAuth:
        users:
          - "test:$apr1$H6uskkkW$IgXLP6ewTrSuBkTrqE8wj/"
          - "test2:$apr1$d9hr9HBB$4HxwgUir3HP4EsggP/QNo0"
```

---

When i try to acces dashboard through domain, i get "404 not found":

```
curl -H Host:traefik.example.com http://127.0.0.1
```

What is wrong in configurations ?

Answer (score 0):

With curl you're using `traefik.example.com` as host, whereas your whoami-label rule is matching only `whoami.docker.server`. Try changing either of those.